# select all cells between two cells that contain string in a column python pandas

Tags: pandas, selection

Good day! I have a data frame df1 with 3 columns: "One", "Two", and "Three". Column 'one' looks like:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4OeF.png)

I want to extract everything between 'B' and 'H' and then paste all of that in cell(1,'Two') or next to 'B' in column 'Two'.

Comment: Use `pd.Series.between`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this:

```
df['Two'].iloc[1] = df['One'][df['One'].between('B', 'H', inclusive=False)].tolist()
```

Value at index `1` column `Two` will be:

```
[B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
```

Comment: Thanks! This next question is a little more challenging. Now, what if I have, say a hundred dataframes, but the letters ('A', 'B', 'C', etc.,) are not always in order except that 'B', is always in a row higher than 'H'. I would like to run one script over all the dataframes that will always extract everything between 'B' and 'H' and paste it in the second column next to 'B'. However, this time, I do not want 'B' nor 'H' included in the extraction. Rather they just serve as references.

Comment: Just realized I can set the 'inclusive' parameter to 'False' to exclude 'B' and 'H'.

Comment: @Ben Wanted to write you exactly that :)